# How to assign date to given variable correctly

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to get reference date as previous saturday when the query is executed before wednesday,after that reference date is executed day.and I want to reuse this reference date as `reference_date` . to achieve this, I write following queries.But when I try to assign date to `reference_date` it returned errors.

Are there any way to achieve this ?
Thanks

```
select into reference_date 
    case
        when date_part(dw, current_date) <= 3 then (
            current_date - (
                date_part(dw, current_date) :: integer + 1
            )
        )
        else current_date
    end;
    
select reference_date;
```

Comment: You can only do this in pl/pgsql. In plain SQL you may try a CTE to mimic a variable. There is a problem in the query too, `dw` causes an error. Change it to `'isodow'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select 
    case
        when date_part('dow', current_date) <= 3 
        then current_date - (date_part('dow', current_date) :: integer + 1)
        else current_date
    end
into reference_date ;
```